# How to convert the (yytext) from small letters to capital letters (in Lex & yacc)?

Tags: yacc, bison, lex

Please, how can i convert a matched string in lex (yytext) from small letters to capital letters? If you can provide me an example i would be grateful.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `toupper` function from the c standard library?

You'll have to loop over the string of course, so you probably want to wrap it up in a function of your own, or if you are already using some external utility library (glib, qt, ...) they may provide a general string case fixer.

Glib seem to provide `g_string_ascii_up`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been trying the following:
<code>
<label>. {fprintf(yyout, toupper('a'));} 
</code>
but it is not working! it is reporting the following:

warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Any suggestions? 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user547894: the warning is telling you exactly what is going on -- fprintf wants a pointer (a string) and you're passing it a single character.  You need to put the character into a string somewhere and pass a pointer to the string

Comment: @user: You could use `fprintf(yyout,"%c",toupper(...));`. Also note that backticks (the kinda backwards single quote) will get you code formatting in a comment.

Comment: Oh Thanks! it is working just i have one last quick question: 

<code>

<label>.+    {
  for(i = 0; i < yyleng; i++)
  fprintf(yyout,"%c",toupper(*yytext)); yymore();
      } 
<\code>

Now here in the above code, it is converting only one character, i think i am doing something wrong. Please any suggestions? 
Thanks so much for all your time and efforts through helping me through this.